# React component state refactoring using ES7

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-2016

Can someone help me refactor this code in the ES7 format? I have it setup per ES7 syntax but I get "this.makeNewQuestion" undefined.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Game  extends Component{
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const valuesArray = this.makeNewQuestion();
        this.state = {
          value1: valuesArray[0],
          value2: valuesArray[1],
          value3: valuesArray[2],
          proposedAnswer: valuesArray[3],
        };
      }

      makeNewQuestion = () => {
        const value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        const value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        const value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        const proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + (value1 + value2 + value3);
        return [value1, value2, value3, proposedAnswer];
      };

      someOtherNonFatArrowMethod(){

      }

      render(){
      return <h2 />
     }
    }
```

What I have in ES7 format is like this. It looks correct to me, but I get this.makeNewQuestion being undefined. that doesn't make any sense to me. Can anyone help me spot what I am missing here?

```
class Game extends Component{
  state = {
    value1: this.generateQuestions()[0],
    value2: this.generateQuestions()[1],
    value3: this.generateQuestions()[2],
    proposedAnswer: this.generateQuestions()[3]
  };

  generateQuestions = () => {
    const value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + (value1 + value2 + value3);
    return [value1, value2, value3, proposedAnswer];
  };

someNonFatArrowFunc(){}
render(){
 return <h2/>
}
}
```

Also how do I avoid having to run makeNewQuestion multiple times in the state? where else would I capture the result of makeNewFunction() inside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `state` to [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and do necessary logic inside.

```js
const {
  Component
} = React

class Game extends Component {

  state = (() => {

    const random = (to, from = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from));

    const makeNewQuestion = () => {
      const value1 = random(100);
      const value2 = random(100);
      const value3 = random(100);
      const proposedAnswer = random(3) + (value1 + value2 + value3);
      return [value1, value2, value3, proposedAnswer];
    };

    const [value1, value2, value3, proposedAnswer] = makeNewQuestion();

    // if you want to use those functions later (ie. event handling ) you have to bind them .
    this.makeNewQuestion = makeNewQuestion;
    this.random = random;

    return {
      value1,
      value2,
      value3,
      proposedAnswer
    }

  })();

  someOtherNonFatArrowMethod() {

  }

  render() {
    return <h2 > Test < /h2>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Game / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying not to use the ES6 constructor, rather I want to skip it and use the ES7 field initializer syntax for the sake of brevity of my code

Comment: Updated answer. Most ES7 property initializer examples assume you are going to hardcode some values, and later, in some lifecycle method update it. Workaround is `IIFE` with lambda functions inside it

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Is there any benefit in creating some as arrow methods and some as regular functions within a React component, especially if the regular functions are only meant to be helper methods inside the component and not meant to used as event handlers?

Comment: I would keep those functions in a separate module/file. Especially the ones where data is computed, fetched